# UINavigationController and the UIViewController's navigation controller property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I happened across this recently, and I was wondering why this is designed as such.

If you have a `UINavigationController` who has a child with a container view that has an embedded view controller in it, why does this child's `self.navigationController` property not get set to something?

From the Apple Doc's on the subject:

> The nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a navigation controller. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController
> Discussion
> If the receiver or one of its ancestors is a child of a navigation controller, this property contains the owning navigation controller. This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a navigation controller.

To me, I would think because it's parent is embedded into the navigation controller, that it would pass it's reference down the chain to it's children. Am I missing something? Is there a good reason this is NOT the case?

Comment: How are you adding the child view controller? Perhaps something is going wrong there.

Comment: In IB: NavController-rootview->ViewControllerA's container view-embed segue->ViewControllerB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I had the same problem as you do. I fixed it by having this code to show the view controller:

```
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        AboutTheAppViewController *loginVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aboutMenuSegueID"];
        [self addChildViewController:loginVC];
        [loginVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        [self.view addSubview:loginVC.view];
```

Then I add this to the AboutTheAppViewController (my controller that is going to be shown):

```
 -(void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent

{
     NSLog(@"FirstViewController moving to or from parent view controller");
 //    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
}

-(void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
   NSLog(@"FirstViewController did move to parent view controller");
//    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 528);
}
```

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: It's interesting that this works, considering it doesn't work in IB. I was looking for an IB solution, and moreover wondering if this was an intentional state of affairs as opposed to just being an oversight. I will accept this answer if no one else has anything on that question.

Comment: @Erik I'm glad it helped. I'm not sure if it is possible, but I will have a look and see what I can find. Ok, as much as I would like to have the answer accepted, I hope you will find a better one :)